# data type mismatch in criteria expression. in c#

Tags: .net

```
/*connection ,command, and link between connection & command objects are done properly and they are working*/

cmd.CommandText = "Update student SET sname='"+snaame+"',fee='"+fees+"' where sno='"+snum+"'";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteReader();
con.Close();
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: First thing to do: use parameterized SQL instead of including the values directly in the SQL. That may well be enough to fix the problem, as well as having a host of other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of `fee` and `sno` in the database those may not be `varchar` if so then remove single quotes around it

```
fee='"+fees+"' where sno='"+snum+"'"
```